# How to check if the next element in a text file is 1 more than the previous element?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a programming homework question:
What is a good method to create a script that checks if the next element in a text file is equal to the previous plus 1 and report back the line in the text file that fails to meet this condition?

The text file looks like:

```
1
3
2
4
```

What I have so far:

```
filename=input('filename')
easy_text_file = open(filename, "rU")
store=1
count=0
for entry in easy_text_file:
    entry_without_newline = entry[:-1]
    data_list=list(entry_without_newline)
if store != data_list[0]:
    print(store)
    print(data_list[0])
    count=count+1
    print('This line does not satisfy the condition at line: ',count)
    break
store=data_list[0]
print(store)
count=count+1
```

If I edit the text file to be:

```
1
2
3
4
6
5
```

It still returns "This line does not satisfy the condition at line:  1"

Comment: You can read each line, convert it to a number, advance the file pointer to the next line, read it, convert it to a number - do your comparison.

Comment: Your title says _next element in a list_, your question says _next element in a text file_. Which is it?

Comment: `myFunc = lambda infilepath : (with open(infilepath) as infile: lines = [int(line.strip()) for line in infile]; for i,tup in enumerate(zip(lines, lines[1:]): (if tup[1]-tup[0]!=1: print(i))))`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is an "I can haz teh codez plz" question

Comment: I have changed the title and added what I have. My error is TypeError: 'list' object is not callable.

Comment: @GeneralStubbs Are you using `list` as a variable anywhere in your code?

Comment: I closed my other python instances and it works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another alternative :

```
easy_text_file = open("number.txt", "rU")

#directly iterate each line of easy_text_file, convert it to int and create list
initial = [int(line) for line in easy_text_file]

#Based your requirement : next value should be equal to previous + 1
#So we create list with starting point from first value to length of initial list 
compare = range(initial[0], len(initial)+1)

#Using zip function to create a match tuple between those list
#Output of zip(initial, compare) => [(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(5,4), ....]
#Then we compare between each values
for i, j in zip(initial, compare):
    if i!=j:
        print 'This line does not satisfy the condition at line: ', j
        break

easy_text_file.close()
```

result :

```
>>> 
This line does not satisfy the condition at line:  4
>>> initial
[1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 3, 5]
>>> compare
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>>
```

Comment: Please use `with` for files.

Comment: Thank you very much. This zip function is perfect and it is only 8 lines and no imports.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that, you just have to keep track on two consecutive lines and check the condition for pair of lines -> 1-2  2-3  3-4  4-5 ...
This code works fine, I am just reading a line and keeping the track of previous line.

```
x=True
count=0
f=open("text.txt")
for line in f:
    if (x==True):   #This condition will be true just once.(for first line only)
        prevline=line
        line = f.next() #reading the second line. I will save this line as previous line. 
        x=False
a=int(prevline) #typecasting
b=int(line)
a=a+1
if(a!=b):
    print "this line does not satisfy the condition at line:",count
prevline=line #keeping the track of previous line
count=count+1
f.close()
```

Comment: Please use `with` for files.

Comment: I appreciate your comment, Can you pleas make me understand why it is better to use "with" for files than "for"?..I tried both the codes and they are working fine..thank you

Comment: `with`, not `while`. `with` replaces `f.close()` and it's better because it's exception-safe.

Answer (score 1):

Read the first line of the file before entering the loop. This will allow you to initialise the expected sequence without assuming that the first number in the file is 1.

Once initialised, just keep track of the value that you expect on the next line, read a line from the file, convert it to an integer, compare it to the expected value, and print an error message if the values do not agree.

You don't need to convert each line to a list, just use [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) - which also ignores new line characters. You should also handle non-numeric data - `int()` will raise `ValueError` if it can't convert the line to a valid integer.

Also, you can keep track of line numbers using a counter (as per your code), or by using [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Putting all of that together you might code it like this:

```
filename = input('filename')
with open(filename, 'rU') as easy_text_file:
    expected = int(next(easy_text_file)) + 1    # initialise next line from first line

    for line_number, entry in enumerate(easy_text_file, 2):
        try:
            entry = int(entry)
            if entry != expected:
                print("Line number {} does not satisfy the condition: expected {}, got {!r}".format(line_number, expected, entry))
            expected = entry + 1
        except ValueError:
            print("Line number {} does not contain a valid integer: {!r}".format(line_number, entry)
```

Answer (score 1):

- Build a generator to return each line as an `int`
- Read the first line, and build a counter that yields the expected values
- Compare each value and expected value
- Where they differ, print the line number, the value and expected value and break
- Where a break didn't occur (the `else` associated with the `for`) - print all good

Eg:

```
from itertools import count

with open('testing.txt') as fin:
    lineno = 0
    lines = map(int, fin)
    try:
        expected = count(next(lines) + 1)
        for lineno, (fst, snd) in enumerate(zip(lines, expected), 2):
            if fst != snd:
                print('problem on line {}: got {}, expected {}'.format(lineno, fst, snd))
                break
        else:
            print('All was fine')
    except StopIteration:
        print('File was empty')
    except ValueError as e:
        print('Error converting line {} - {}'.format(lineno + 1, e))
```